# Tensorflow different shapes with example code

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes

I'm new to tensorflow and I'm trying to learn it.

I'm trying to use the provided Iris example ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/tflearn/index.html)) with my own data.

I have this CSV:

```
  2262,2013,2452,2260,2279,2340,2160,2404,5162,6259,4882,2544,2365,2293,2333,2283,2063,2156,2427,2305,1
  2316,2423,2350,2150,2241,2167,2086,3109,4312,6150,4761,2837,2464,2135,2455,2339,2417,2281,2016,2284,1
  ...
```

And so on (21 columns and 45 rows, where the last one is the category).

I have only 2 categories (0 and 1) and I'm using this code

```
  training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header(filename="data.csv",
                                                   target_dtype=numpy.int,features_dtype=numpy.int,target_column=20)
  # Specify that all features have real-value data
  feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("",dimension=20)]


  # Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
     classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                        hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                        n_classes=2,
                                        model_dir="/tmp/24-10")

   classifier.fit(x=training_set.data, y=training_set.target, steps=2000)
```

The error I get is about shape, but I don't seem to find what is wrong with this code

Error (on line relative to fit instruction):

```
ValueError: Shapes (?, 1) and (?,) are incompatible
```

Thank you

Comment: It's not a bug or smth actually. Those shapes are basically equivalent, the only difference is the first has an extra dimension of 1. Just resize an input to correspondent shape with tf.reshape().

Comment: I can't. 
If i try to reshape one or both or them i get this error:
`ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`
It seems like that training_set.target is a single row while it must be a single colon; also tried with transpose but `fit` tells me that inputs cannot be tensors

Comment: Try using `numpy.reshape` to reshape the inputs before feeding them to the classifier. Does that work?